# Why is my patch coming out in binary format?

Tags: diff, patch

I'm diffing two directories, 220 and sue, as follows:

```
diff -r 220 sue > diff.txt
```

The directory looks as follows afterwards:

```
$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     0 Jun 24 10:44 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM           0 Jun 24 09:52 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     0 Jun 24 09:54 220
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jempty         Domain Users 15463 Jun 24 10:44 diff.txt
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users     0 Jun 24 09:55 sue
```

Confirming diff.txt is text as follows:

```
$ file diff.txt
diff.txt: HTML document, ASCII text, with very long lines, with CRLF, LF line terminators
```

The above is primarily to demonstrate that I can use diff and see that there not a tremendous amount of differences.

Then creating a patch file as suggested by https://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_patch:

```
$ diff -Naur 220 sue > patch.txt
```

Results in the directory looking as follows:

```
$ ls -al
total 133836
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users         0 Jun 24 10:57 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM         SYSTEM               0 Jun 24 09:52 ..
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users         0 Jun 24 09:54 220
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jempty         Domain Users     15463 Jun 24 10:44 diff.txt
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 jempty         Domain Users 137024100 Jun 24 10:57 patch.txt
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators Domain Users         0 Jun 24 09:55 sue
```

As you can see the patch.txt file is enormous and as it turns out it's binary:

```
$ file patch.txt
patch.txt: data
```

Should I be using the `patch` command instead of `diff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have binary files (programs, DLLs, data files, etc.) in either `220` or `sue`, or both.

The first command (`diff -r`) recognizes that some files are binary, and when this is the case, `diff` will simply print a message that they differ. For example, if both `220` and `sue` have a binary file `foo.dat` in them, you would expect the output to be something like this:

```
Binary files 220/foo.dat and sue/foo.dat differ
```

The second command has the `-a` flag, which tells `diff` to unconditionally treat all files as plaintext, so it will compare and print the raw, binary content of the differences between `220/foo.dat` and `sue/foo.dat`. Since `diff` compares line-by-line, and binary files typically have few line breaks, the lines compared and shown in the output will be fairly large, even for relatively small files.

To reduce the size of `diff`'s output, don't use the `-a` flag:

```
$ diff -Nur 220 sue > patch.txt
```

If you don't care about the differences between binary files, you can filter the output to exclude them:

```
$ diff -Nur 220 sue | grep -v '^Binary files.*differ' > patch.txt
```

---

To answer your last question, `patch` is the opposite of `diff`, so you wouldn't use `patch` here. You use `diff` to find the differences between files, and you use `patch` to apply the differences from `diff`'s output to those files. The terms are used interchangeably when referring to the output of `diff`.